# iPhone app with audio files is just too big. How do I reduce the size?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a BlackBerry app that I am about to port to the iPhone. The app contains mp3 files which causes the BlackBerry version to be about 10MB in size (even after I reduced the quality of the files to 92kbps). 10MB won't do for the iPhone. Does anyone know of any best practices when it comes to including audio files in your iPhone app? I'm interested in knowing suggested format(s), quality, channels (left, right) etc. I will also need to play more than one file at a time (very important).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider downloading (some of) the MP3 files after your app is installed.  For low bitrate you're better off recompressing with AAC though (perhaps at 48-64 kbps); it provides better quality than MP3 at the same size.  Also consider mono instead of stereo if it makes no difference.

Comment: I was going to post the same thing -- AAC could make the difference for you, especially if you ditch the stereo channel.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't 10 MB for the iPhone work?

Applications on the iPhone can be as large as 2 GB with apps larger than 10 MB can be downloaded over wifi or through iTunes.

Comment: I've had cases where I've tried to download an app only to get a message saying that I needed to download the app over wifi. I never got around to downloading any of those apps. I would like to, if possible, to keep the app size small enough so that it can be downloaded via the 3G network. If that's not possible, fine. But I would at least like to try to keep it as small as possible without sacrificing sound quality.